# File indexing and search library/API for .Net applications

Tags: .net, search, document-indexing

I am developing a WinForms .Net application. It does a a lot of management type things, but the important part is that it allows users to add file attachments - and they add *lots* of these.

I now have a requirement to provide search functionality for these file attachments, and it must include content. So to that end, my requirements are as follows:

1. Ability to create a search index on a given folder structure
2. Index function must be able to read common document formats correctly (such as Microsoft Office documents, XML, PDF, HTML, etc.)
3. API functions should allow search for specific keywords, and also basic filtering options such as file types
4. Must be actively supported and maintained, so new document types (like new MS Office releases) are added as they are released
5. Licencing must permit a single, one-off payment that allows unlimited distribution with our software (ongoing yearly support fees are fine though)
6. Performance is important, searches need to be acceptable fast
7. Needs to cope with *large* amounts of files (500GB-1TB, 1,000,000+ files)
8. Desirable to have a document viewer that supports search hit highlighting

Essentially we have been evaluating dtSearch and it's a great product (maybe even too great for what little functionality I actually want to use), however there are some sticking points with licencing and I am looking to evaluate alternatives.

Please let me know if you need clarifications on any points.